# Program doesn't send parameters to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote program which selects and should delete a row from gridview based on the `ID` but it throws an exception that `@ComplainantTypeID` is not provided to the stored procedure but I checked in debugging, it sends and adds value but it still throws exception.

Code:

```
protected void btnDeletePopUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            int ComplainantTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(txtSelectedID.Text.Trim());
            ManageComplainantType mngComplainantType = new ManageComplainantType();
            mngComplainantType.Delete(ComplainantTypeID);
            Clear(txtName, txtSelectedID);
            HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "Delete";
            HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "NotDeleted";
            HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
        }
    }
```

Delete function in BLL:

```
public void Delete(int ComplainantTypeID)
{
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteComplainantTypes_SP", DataBaseConnection.OpenConnection());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter pComplainantTypeID = new SqlParameter("@ComplainantTypeID", ComplainantTypeID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pComplainantTypeID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataBaseConnection.CloseConnection();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteComplainantTypes_SP]
    @ComplainantTypeID smallint
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
       DELETE FROM ComplainantTypes WHERE ComplainantTypeID = @ComplainantTypeID
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
       SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
   END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Can you try changing the proc parameter name to @test and same in code and check. Also just pass value like this SqlParameter("@test", 1); and see if you still get the same error. I tried your code in local and it just works fine for me.

Comment: Can you try cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplainantTypeID", 1);       remove SqlParameter line

Comment: @Rishikesh yes sir, it worked, but why ?

Comment: It seems that .net runtime is not able to map datatype when you write like that. I think this code would also have worked SqlParameter pComplainantTypeID = new SqlParameter("@ComplainantTypeID",SqlDbType.SmallInt,value); I have added this as answer , please accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplainantTypeID", value);
```

or

```
SqlParameter pComplainantTypeID = new SqlParameter("@ComplainantTypeID",SqlDbType.SmallInt,value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must show exception for better assistance, but the problem actually is in data type. You pass `int` but expected `smallint`. Look at the [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article to choose appropriate data type.

**UPDATE**

You cant convert int to `smallint` you must pass parameter of type `short` which maps to `smallint` sql type.

Declare

```
public void Delete(short ComplainantTypeID)
```

instead of

```
public void Delete(int ComplainantTypeID)
```

and keep SP unchanged.

Comment: ERROR: Store procedure excepts @ComplainantTypeID which was not supplied

Comment: In that case it would have given "Error converting data type int to smallint" eror

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ComplainantTypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ComplainantTypeID;
```